# SQLite.NET PCL multi thread access MONO

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, sqlite.net

I have been using `SQLite.Net` for `Monodroid` and `Monotouch`, To avoid problems with access across threads I used this code to set `Serialized` mode.

```
    SQLite.SQLite3.Shutdown();
    SQLite.SQLite3.Config(SQLite.SQLite3.ConfigOption.Serialized);
    SQLite.SQLite3.Initialize();
```

and this did stop any problems (getting `SIGSEVC` errors).

I have now attempted to move my library code to `PCL`, so mow using `oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL`
but the option to set Config mode seems not to exist anymore. Searching through the code I have found that in `SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLiteApi` the following line.

```
//        Result Config(ConfigOption option);
```

so the ability to set the config is not implemented.

Now once again I am getting my `SIGSEVC` error on Monodroid when my background thread returns with updates from a web service.

The database connection is shared using a static connection, and all database access via lock(object).

Questions:

1. Is it possible to set the Config to Serialized somehow?
2. or, is there a better way for me to define my connection and database access to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed the best way to fix it was to modify the source of the SQLite.Net-PCL. I have done this implementing the missing features.

this required the dll imports and concrete implementations to be created for each platform.

Full details are on the GitHub project here https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/35